# How to append an object to an empty object

Tags: javascript, json

I have multiple questions in a form and I am trying to append each answer to an empty object:

```
const y = document.createElement("INPUT");
      y.setAttribute("class", "textBox");
      y.setAttribute("id", "fourthQID");
      window.data.appendChild(y);

for (const o of i.options){

        const x = document.createElement("INPUT");
        x.setAttribute("type", "radio");
        x.setAttribute("id", "radioID");
        x.name = "RadioBtn";
        x.value = o;

        const y = document.createElement("LABEL");
        const t = document.createTextNode(o);
        y.appendChild(t);

        const div = document.createElement("div");
        div.style.height = "5px";
        div.appendChild(x);
        div.appendChild(y);
        document.getElementById("radioButton").appendChild(div);


        window.data.appendChild(x);
        window.data.appendChild(y);
        window.data.appendChild(div);
      }

const answers = [];
const data = {"answers": []};

const fourthQuestion = JSON.stringify(document.getElementById('fourthQID').value);
const fifthQuestion = JSON.stringify(document.querySelector("input[name=RadioBtn]:checked").value);
```

I have tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
answers.push(firstQuestion);
    answers.push(secondQuestion);
    data.answers.push(firstQuestion);
    data.answers.push(secondQuestion);
```

How can I get the answers from the form as a JSON in `answers = []`?

Comment: if you want the `answers` in `data` to be the same, the use `const data = { answers }` then both will be references to the same array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To append each answer to an empty object try Object.assign().

```
// The Object.assign() method copies all enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target object. It returns the target object.

const returnedTarget = Object.assign(target, source);
```

Better solution is to use FormData(). For example:

```
// get form values
const myForm = document.forms.FORM_NAME_ATTRIBUTE;
// init new FormData() object
const formData = new FormData();

// Add form elements to formData object
[...myForm.elements].forEach((element) => {
     if (element.name.length > 0) {
       formData.append(element.name, element.value);
     }       
});

// or use formData.append() to add elements
formData.append(el.name, el.value);

// and then stringify FormData
var object = {};
formData.forEach(function(value, key){
    object[key] = value;
});
var json = JSON.stringify(object);
```